# DateTimePicker: how to set MinDate before 1753

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I am building a [genealogical tree app](https://github.com/xavierpena/family_tree), and I need to reach past this date. I would prefer DateTimePicker rather than TextBox + text-date conversion.

Is there anyway to circumvent this limitation?

Comment: No, hard limit.  1753 was the year that England switched from the Julian to the Gregorian calender, causing 15 days to be lost.  Black hole avoidance by a Sybase programmer, the company that started SQL Server.  You'll have to make your own.

Comment: You're going to have to create your own data type to handle dates, with a Year, Month and Day property. You could also roll your own methods and properties for simple functions like CompareTo(), and AddYears(), AddDays() etc. Unfortunately this also means making your own calendar control to edit those dates.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the `DateTimePicker` control does not support dates before January 1, 1753. This is ultimately due to limitations in the [Date and Time Picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Month Calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) controls in the [`ComCtl32` Common Controls library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Those controls do not support dates before 1753 because that is the dividing line between the Gregorian and Julian calendars. Since the controls are based on the Gregorian calendar, they do not calculate dates consistent with the Julian calendar.

The reason this affects .NET code is because the `DateTimePicker` class is a wrapper around the lower-level `comctl32` controls. The relevant code is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DateTimePicker.cs.html#68f0ebcdf3a7ed6e).

Sadly, this limitation is also carried over into [the Mono implementation of the control](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/DateTimePicker.cs#L56), so even if you use `DateTimePicker` through Mono on Linux or Mac, it still will not allow dates before then, despite the lack of a `comctl32.dll` in the operating system.

It looks like Telerik has [their own `DateTimePicker` control](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/editors/datetimepicker/datetimepicker). That might be worthy of investigation. After a quick scan of the docs, though, I do not see what its limits are, if any.